# How to upgrade to ubuntu 17.04 from 16.04 using command line?

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade my ubuntu to recent version which contains latest kernel 4.10.
I saw following links.
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html
and
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts
but it didn't work. 
How can I upgrade 17.04 from 16.04.2 in command line?

Comment: 17.04 is not officially released yet and therefore we do not support it here yet. But anyway, you can not directly upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04, you must first upgrade to the next and currently latest release 16.10. The command to do that is `do-release-upgrade`. It is always strongly recommended to make a backup of your important data first, just in case something might go wrong.

Comment: You can currently also get a newer kernel up to version 4.8.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 by installing the HWE kernel stack.

Comment: Or get Ubuntu 17.04 .iso image from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/)